# How to reset Excel 2010 settings to Default?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel-2010, display-settings, default-settings

Excel's cells are very small when at 100% zoom (see screenshot below):

[image: SU525713 example]

I have searched Excel's menu but couldn't find anything relevant. I tried to install Microsoft Fixit but it said it wasn't supported by my operating system (Windows 7 Home Basic).

Can anyone help restore the look of my sheet to 'as default' please?

Comment: Did you try repairing or reinstalling Excel?

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. It was installed when i bought the machine. For now I don't have office licence and until I buy a new one i need to use this installed version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reset the customized user settings automatically by using Microsofts Fixit, click the  link (http://download.microsoft.com/download/B/0/C/B0C6EEE0-47D4-47FD-AA50-CABAA515D0D8/MicrosoftFixit50274.msi) to download Microsoft Fix it 50274
Click Run in the File Download dialog box, and follow the steps in the Fix it wizard.

Answer (score 3):

1. Close all office programs.
2. Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
3. Type `regedit` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. First backup this key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Excel`
5. Then delete it.
6. Reopen excel.

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1**

Click the Start button and open the "Control Panel." 
**Step 2** 
Click the "Uninstall a program" link under Programs. 
**Step 3** 
Scroll down and highlight "Microsoft Office." 
**Step 4** 
Click the "Change" button and wait for a new window to open. 
**Step 5** 
Click to select the "Repair" option and click "Continue" to authorize your computer to repair Microsoft Excel to its default settings.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. I tried repairing but it didn't succeed

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

1. Run `regedit` and go to the following path:

   ```
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Excel
   ```
2. Delete the `OPTIONS` folder.

Excel will create it again when open.